# Rails 5: check if role ID belongs to user belonging to current_user (through association)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

In my *controllers/common/roles_controller.rb* I would like to check if particular role (ID) belongs to current_user company users and if not, redirect to *errors_path*:

```
def correct_role
  role_user = Role.where(:id => params[:id]).select('user_id').first
  company_user = current_user.companies.includes(:users)
  redirect_to(errors_path) unless company_user.include? role_user.id
end
```

Definitions:

- `role_user` - finds user ID for particular role ID ("user_id" is column of roles table)
- `company_user` - finds all user ID who belong to companies, which belong to current_user

*models/role.rb*

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true, inverse_of: :roles
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

enum general: { seller: 1, buyer: 2, seller_buyer: 3}, _suffix: true
enum dashboard: { denied: 0, viewer: 1, editer: 2, creater: 3, deleter: 4}, _suffix: true
```

*models/user.rb*

```
#User has roles
  has_many :roles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes[:name].blank? }

  # User has many companies
  has_many :accounts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :companies, through: :accounts
```

*models/account.rb*

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company, :user
end
```

*models/company.rb*

```
has_many :accounts, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :accounts
```

At the moment with `role_user` and `company_user` I can find both ID, however **I cannot do the checking part**. How do I do that correctly, please? Thank you for any help!

**Update**

@sajan code give this in console when I open */common/roles/1/edit* (current_user ID=1 and should be allowed to edit):

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "companies" INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "companies"."id" = "accounts"."company_id" WHERE "accounts"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
(0.3ms)  SELECT "roles".id FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
```

@Abhishek Kumar code in console gives:

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
    User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
    Company Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "companies"."id" = "accounts"."company_id" WHERE "accounts"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
    (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".id FROM "users" INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "users"."id" = "accounts"."user_id" WHERE "accounts"."company_id" = ?  [["company_id", 13]]
    Role Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "roles"."user_id" FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = ? ORDER BY "roles"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

**Update v2**

So I'm trying to use this code:

```
def correct_role
company_user_ids = current_user.companies.map(&:user_ids)
role_user = Role.where(:id => params[:id]).select('user_id').first
unless role_user.user_id.in?(company_user_ids)
redirect_to(errors_path)
end
end
```

however it redirects to errors_path in any case, this is what I have in console:

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Company Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "companies"."id" = "accounts"."company_id" WHERE "accounts"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
(0.4ms)  SELECT "users".id FROM "users" INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "users"."id" = "accounts"."user_id" WHERE "accounts"."company_id" = ?  [["company_id", 13]]
Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "roles"."user_id" FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = ? ORDER BY "roles"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a better logic would be to define on the model for the current_user an association through companies and users to roles.

Then you can check:

```
def correct_role
  redirect_to(errors_path) unless current_user.company_user_roles.where(id: params[:id]).exists?
end
```

It would be a single SQL statement that would return zero or one rows, and execute very quickly with the appropriate indexes in place.

Edit:

To company.rb, add:

```
has_many :user_roles, through: :users, source: :roles
```

To user.rb (assuming that current_user is an instance of this model) add:

```
has_many :company_user_roles, through: :companies, source: :user_roles
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I added company model above. Please, can you give an example, how should models look like? I'm quite a beginner :)

Comment: Thank you, seems like it is working :) Big, big thanks for saving me. Rails community rocks!

Comment: No problem -- if something looks complicated, it's probably being done wrong ;)

Comment: Yes, true! Your code works like charm, thanks again ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do like this:

```
def correct_role
  unless current_user.companies.count > 0 && current_user.role_ids.include?(params[:id])
    redirect_to(errors_path)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, however I get syntax error: unexpected tIDENTIFIER expecting keyword_end

Comment: Try now with the edited answer, I have removed one space. And the error is happening because somewhere you missed to close a block with a `end` line. check for it.

Comment: seems it is close, but not yet - please, can you check what console gives me above in Update?

Comment: So what is the issue ? Is it redirecting to `errors_path` ? If this is the case then please check that you have a role with `user_id = 1`. and `current_user` has at least 1 company

Comment: Yes, its error. `current_user` has ID=1 and in roles table column `user_id = 1` For example, `current_user` has two roles to be edited `(1, 3)` as there are two users belonging to company, where in roles table `user_id = (1, 3)`

Comment: I am not sure that I got your point. Can you give me values you are testing with ? Like what is the value of `params[:id]`, `current_user.role_ids` and `current_user.companies.count` so I can check where condition is failing

Comment: Ok, this is what I have: a) I'm editing role `id: 1` where `user_id: 1` b) roles with ids 1 and 3 belongs to current_user through companies (in my case single company has two users). current_user should be able to edit roles 1 and 3 as those belong to users who belong to company which belong to curent_user.

Comment: Ok, message me in SO chat. We will discuss there

Comment: Or get the values from rails console and post the values here. `current_user.role_ids` and `current_user.companies.count`

Comment: `current_user.role_ids` = 1, 3  and  `current_user.companies.count` = 1

Comment: Then it should work. Can you debug a little in rails server console when that block executes ? like put a `byebug` below the line `def correct_role` and in when code runs, in console try to evaluate every part of the condition i.e `current_user.companies.count > 0` and `current_user.role_ids.include?(params[:id])` . If any evaluates to `false` let me know